# Upgrading to Rails 5 problems - existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently tried to update to Rails 5 and it won't seem to work. I switched it over in my gemfile from 4.2.6 and deleted the gemfile.lock. I then ran `gem update rails` which seemed to work fine, but then I ran `bundle update` and I got these errors

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
 In Gemfile:
  rails (= 5.0.0)

  devise-heroku was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
   rails (>= 3.1.1)

  interactor-rails (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
   rails (< 5, >= 3)
```

I can't seem to find much documentation on this. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from the output you got, interactor-rails 1.0 does not support Rails 5. I checked out their page, and it looks like you need to bundle 2.0 version of that gem.

```
gem "interactor-rails", "~> 2.0"
```

You can read the docs [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/interactor-rails)

You might need to upgrade the devise-heroku gem as well.